# Pattern match scala predef class to AnyRef

Tags: scala

```
def cast(c: Class[_]): Unit = {
  c match {
    case AnyRef => // do stuff
    case _ => // do stuff
  }
}
```

This fails with

```
[scalac-2.11]  error: type mismatch;
[scalac-2.11]  found   : Specializable
[scalac-2.11]  required: Class[_$2] where type _$2
[scalac-2.11]       case AnyRef =>
```

Not sure why this won't compile? It makes sense to me that an input class can be an instance of AnyRef or not

Comment: `case AnyRef` is matching the companion object `AnyRef` not a value that is a subclass of `AnyRef`, not the `Class[AnyRef]` what are you trying to do, that code looks awfully unsafe and very Javaesque.

Comment: `Class` is always `AnyRef` because it's object. What problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need to pattern match against Class?